# Sectioning code in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way of sectioning the code in `sql-server` except using `begin-end`?

Something similar to `#region` use in visual studio.

It is hard to jump in to specific section when there are large numbers of lines in the code

Comment: Stored procedures and functions can help migrate huge numbers of lines of code elsewhere also, but that's not enough for you? Dont want to mean, just curious, sounds almost like a large pile "legacy code" :)

Answer (score 2):

Not natively, you'll need a third party tool for that.

[**SSMS Tools Pack**](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features) by Mladen Prajdić gives you `#region` functionality, along with a lot of others.  Not free, but very, very good.